# Intermittent error 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Tags: php, object, iteration

We are getting a PHP notice on our production server:

```
[PHP Notice] Trying to get property of non-object
```

In our code we have two arrays of `Foo` objects each with a `pos` member variable:

```
$locked_foos
$unlocked_foos
```

I'm running a while loop to order and merge these `Foo`s into a new array result:

```
$cur_pos = 1;
$result  = [];

// Extract first locked and unlocked foos
$locked_foo = reset($locked_foos);
$unlocked_foo = reset($unlocked_foos);

// While there is either an unlocked or locked foo..
while($locked_foo || $unlocked_foo){

  // If there is no unlocked (thus must be a locked) or the locked's position is current..
  if(!$unlocked_foo || $locked_foo->pos == $cur_pos){ // **Error**

    // Use locked, set pos and iterate locked
    $locked_foo->pos = $cur_pos;
    $result[] = $locked_foo;

    $locked_foo = next($locked_foos);
  }
  // Else..
  else {

    // Use unlocked, set pos and iterate unlocked
    $unlocked_foo->pos = $cur_pos;
    $result[] = $unlocked_foo;

    $unlocked_foo = next($unlocked_foos);
  }

  // Iterate current position
  $cur_pos++;
}
```

The error occurs at the line shown.

I assume the error occurs when one of the `$locked_foos` is set to something other than an object, so I added the lines:

```
  if($locked_foo && !is_object($locked_foo)){
    throw new Exception('FOOOO!');
  }
```

Just inside the while loop.

I'm still getting the same error and no exception is thrown, how is this possible?

Comment: i would say its this part here $locked_foo->pos that is breaking.
i would need to see what the reset($locked_foos) function does so i can give you a proper answer.

Comment: @JamesWaring `reset()` is a standard php array function that resets the internal pointer and returns the first element.

Comment: @JamesWaring I had reached the same conclusion, hence the `if(){throw}` that I added, although the error still happens at the same point.

Comment: if $locked_foo is an array shouldn't it be $locked_foo[0]->pos; but if it was then you Exception should have thrown!, do a print_r($locked_foo) and see what is in the var;

Comment: Did you try the `throw` debug with `$unlocked_foo` as well?

Comment: @JamesWaring I can't throw a `print_r` into my production environment unfortunately! `$locked_foos` is an array, `$locked_foo` is set to the first element of the array using `reset()` and then iterated through the array using `next()`

Comment: @caCtus I did yes, although it doesn't affect the question. Sadly.. no exception thrown!

Comment: the only other thing i can think of is if $locked_foos is an empty array.

Comment: @JamesWaring I can't believe I missed that.. thank you kindly.

Comment: was that that answer??

Comment: @JamesWaring Not precisely, it only required `$locked_foos` to run out of elements before `$unlocked_foos`. But an empty `$locked_foos` would recreate the error, I'd managed to confuse myself on the `if` condition logic. So thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my logic was all funky:

```
// If there is no unlocked (thus must be a locked) or the locked's position is current..
if(!$unlocked_foo || $locked_foo->pos == $cur_pos){ // **Error**

  // Use locked, set pos and iterate locked
  $locked_foo->pos = $cur_pos;
  $result[] = $locked_foo;

  $locked_foo = next($locked_foos);
}
```

In the rare case that `$locked_foos` ran out of elements before `$unlocked_foos`, `$unlocked_foo` was positive and `$locked_foo = false`.

I changed the `if` condition to

```
// If there is a locked with the current position or there is no unlocked..
if(
  $locked_foo &&
  ($locked_foo->pos == $cur_pos || !$unlocked_foo)
){
  ..
}
```

which is the correct logic (and possibly more readable too).